# How to get Windows Extended File Properties Date/Times with seconds using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the VBA objFolder.GetDetails method to read the Windows 7 Extended File Properties of several files. I have noticed that all the times are only given in hours and minutes:

```
3   Date modified: 8/16/2018 3:42 PM
4   Date created: 9/11/2018 10:11 AM
5   Date accessed: 9/11/2018 10:13 AM
```

How can I write out these dates with the time in hours:minutes:seconds?

Comment: `objFolder.GetDetails`? Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52282451/edit) to include your code?

Comment: `FileDateTime(pathHere)` includes the seconds portion of the timestamp: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/filedatetime.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the FileSystemObject and not Shell object, I am assuming you are using The Shell object from the GetDetails method being used.

```
Dim fso
Dim f
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFile("filePath")

Debug.Print f.DateCreated
Debug.Print f.DateLastAccessed
Debug.Print f.DateLastModified
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works for the file created, modified and accessed dates. How would I get the Extended File Property "Date Taken" to include seconds? This date/time does not seem to be available via the FileSystemObject.

Comment: @BigJack56  I took what you had in your question which showed those three.  If you are trying to get the Date Taken information from a image then that is another beast altogether, IE another question specifically asking to obtain the Date Taken information from a image file via VBA. IE read image metadata

Comment: Sorceri...I understand your response. Maybe you can explain the following: Microsoft has provided access to file extended properties via the method objFolder.GetDetailsOf which provides access to all the date/time values of interest to me. The only issue is the lack of seconds in the time. The responses to date are pointing me to completely different methods depending on the date/time of interest. Why is this necessary?  Why are the extended file properties date/time limited in precision especially when the addition information (seconds) is available for the file.

Answer (score 0):

From:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/4a4cb944-2342-4f80-a2c6-44be76185825

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim arrHeaders(34)

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:\_Stuff\test")

    For i = 0 To 33
        arrHeaders(i) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.Items, i)
    Next

    For Each strFileName In objFolder.Items
        For i = 0 To 33
            Debug.Print i & vbTab & arrHeaders(i) _
                & ": " & objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, i)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

You should be able to adapt that to your needs.

Comment: This code will not print date/time values with seconds only hours and minutes.

Comment: Maybe try:  https://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Accessing-detailed-file-information-provided-by-the-Operating-System